# Capturing specific keystrokes from a Listbox

Tags: winapi, listbox, keypress, keystroke

I'm trying to make my main window to receive notifications when user presses a Delete key on a listbox's item. I've tried this:

```
case WM_CHARTOITEM:
         if( lParam == (LPARAM)hwndListBox )
         {
            sprintf( debug, "0x%x", LOWORD(wParam) ); 
            MessageBoxA(0, debug, 0, 0);
         }
         break;
```

..and I got all keystrokes except the Delete (and End, Home, Inert, PageUp, PageDown, arrows etc). Though I got Numpad's Delete keystroke.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those keys don't produce a WM_CHAR message.  You'll need WM_VKEYTOITEM to see them.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also, for those who'll find this question: listbox will need a LBS_WANTKEYBOARDINPUT style to produce WM_CKEYTOITEM.